# Position of south components in GWT SplitLayout

Tags: java, gwt, widget, splitpanel

I want to add a south panel to `SplitLayout`.
The [GWT showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwSplitLayoutPanel) shows that you can add two south panel to the `SplitLayout` widget and the layout will place them in order.

My problem is that I only want to put one south panel into `SplitLayout` but I want to position it to the place of the inner south panel. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for my problem:

I used two `SplitLayout`. The outer one has a west and a center panel. This center contains the inner `SplitLayout`, which contains the desired south panel and a center panel.
This way I can get what I wanted; though this solution produces a more complicated html.